# how to simulate click function with css?

Tags: html, css

I would like to simulate the click function with only css.

when the mouse click the first li tag, I wish to dropdown the all list.

This is my simple html code with css , and how could I do?

[jsfiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/nfmp0o4n/)

```html
<div id="lang_sel">
  <ul>
    <li><a href="#">option1</a>
      <ul>
        <li><a href="#">option2</a></li>
        <li><a href="#">option3</a></li>
      </ul>
    </li>
  </ul>
</div>
```

```css
#lang_sel {
  height: 32px;
  position: relative;
  font-family: verdana, arial, sans-serif;
  display: inline-block;
}

#lang_sel ul, #lang_sel li {
  padding: 0!important;
  margin: 0!important;
  list-style-type: none!important;
}
#lang_sel li:before {
  content: ''!important;
}
#lang_sel ul ul {
  width: 149px;
}
#lang_sel li {
  float: left;
  width: 149px;
  position: relative;
}
#lang_sel a, #lang_sel a:visited {
  display: block;
  font-size: 11px;
  text-decoration: none!important;
  color: #444444;
  border: 1px solid #cdcdcd;
  background: #fff;
  padding-left: 10px;
  line-height: 24px;
}
#lang_sel ul ul {
  visibility: hidden;
  position: absolute;
  height: 0;
  top: 25px;
  left: 0;
  width: 149px;
  border-top: 1px solid #cdcdcd;
}
#lang_sel a:hover, #lang_sel ul ul a:hover {
  color: #000;
  background: #eee;
}
#lang_sel ul li:hover ul{
  visibility: visible;
}
```

.........................................

Answer (score 1):

You can use `checkbox` hack

```css
#lang_sel {
 height: 32px;
 position: relative;
 font-family: verdana, arial, sans-serif;
 display: inline-block;
}
#opt{
    width:200px;
    height:30px;
    opacity:0;
}
label{
    display:block;
}
label span{
    top:0;
    width:200px;
    height:30px;
    position:absolute;
}

label ul{
    display:none;
}

input:checked + label ul{
    display:block;
    
}
#lang_sel ul, #lang_sel li {
 padding: 0!important;
 margin: 0!important;
 list-style-type: none!important;
}

#lang_sel ul ul {
 width: 149px;
}
#lang_sel li {
 float: left;
 width: 149px;
 position: relative;
}
#lang_sel a, #lang_sel a:visited {
 display: block;
 font-size: 11px;
 text-decoration: none!important;
 color: #444444;
 border: 1px solid #cdcdcd;
 background: #fff;
 padding-left: 10px;
 line-height: 24px;
}
#lang_sel ul ul {
 visibility: hidden;
 position: absolute;
 height: 0;
 top: 25px;
 left: 0;
 width: 149px;
 border-top: 1px solid #cdcdcd;
}
#lang_sel a:hover, #lang_sel ul ul a:hover {
 color: #000;
 background: #eee;
}
```

```html
<div id="lang_sel">
    <input type="checkbox" id="opt"/>
    <label for="opt">
        <span>Option1</span>
        <ul>
            <li>Suboption</li>
            <li>Suboption</li>
            <li>Suboption</li>
            <li>Suboption</li>
            <li>Suboption</li>
        </ul>
    </label>
</div>
```